# SQL query to find and replace text in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I find and replace specific text in a stored procedure?

I have the find and replace query but I'm not sure how to post that back to the stored procedure or update the stored procedure with the query result.

Here is the query that I am using for the find and replace:

```
SELECT
   REPLACE (object_definition(object_id('storedprocedure_1')), 'findstring', 'replacestring')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Declare @spnames CURSOR
Declare @spname nvarchar(max)
Declare @moddef nvarchar(max)
Set @spnames = CURSOR FOR
select distinct object_name(c.id) 
from syscomments c, sysobjects o 
where c.text like '%findtext%'
and c.id = o.id
and o.type = 'P'    
OPEN @spnames
FETCH NEXT
FROM @spnames into @spname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    Set @moddef =
    (SELECT
    Replace ((REPLACE(definition,'findtext','replacetext')),'ALTER','create')
    FROM sys.sql_modules a
    JOIN 
    (   select type, name,object_id
    from sys.objects b
    where type in (
    'p' -- procedures
    )
    and is_ms_shipped = 0
    )b
    ON a.object_id=b.object_id where b.name = @spname)              
    exec('drop procedure dbo.' + @spname)
    execute sp_executesql @moddef
    FETCH NEXT FROM @spnames into @spname
END
```

This is what I was able to come up with, its currently doing the text replace and re creating the stored procedures.

Comment: this does a days job in 1 hour.

Comment: We can use this code to change other types of objects. I've used it today to change Triggers after changing a buch of triggers to write data on another schema. Easy: change o.type = 'P' by 'TR' and the drop procedure by drop trigger. Thanks @Jay J

Comment: Didn't worked not sure why. I executed nothing gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the definition of a stored procedure like so:

```
use <your database>
go
select
definition
from
sys.sql_modules
where
object_id = OBJECT_ID('<your schema.procedure_name>')
```

That will return the actual definition of the procedure you specify.  You can build a list of stored procedures and walk through that one at a time, I guess. Not so sure I'd recommend trying to change them in sys.sql_modules, but at least you could find the ones that contain the text you're looking for.

Comment: I would need to do update the original definition and this is not a one time task, it has to be done every time a database is restored.  That's is the reason why I am looking to update all the procedure through sql.  I am able to achieve the same using .net stored procedure object (TextBody) but since I am updating around 200+ SP's its taking about 25-30 minutes.  So I want to take the SQL route to see if its faster